# How to get NavView Items to Act like "Push Buttons" instead of "Radio Buttons"?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to get my NavViewItems to act like push buttons instead of toggle buttons.I don't want the NavViewItem Sticking down after its selected.

```
    private void NavView_SelectionChanged(
         NavigationView sender, 
         NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
        {
            NavView.Header = "Settings";
            //rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        }
        else if (args.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            NavigationViewItem item 
               = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;
            NavView.Header = item.Tag;
            // Unclick/Unselect NavViewItem Here <--
        }
    }

}

<Page ... >

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <NavigationView 
              RequestedTheme="Dark" 
              x:Name="NavView" 
              Header="Welcome" 
              SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged">
           <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem 
                     Icon="Home"        
                     Content="Home"            
                     Tag="Home"         
                     Background="Maroon"    
                     Foreground="White"/>
                <NavigationViewItem 
                     Icon="Back"        
                     Content="PrevPage"        
                     Tag="Back"         
                     Background="Maroon"    
                     Foreground="White"/>
                <NavigationViewItem 
                     Icon="Globe"       
                     Content="Enter Info1"   
                     Tag="EnterCompany" 
                     Background="DarkGreen" Foreground="White"/>
                <NavigationViewItem 
                     Icon="PostUpdate"  
                     Content="Enter Info2"       
                     Tag="EnterJob"     
                     Background="DarkGreen" Foreground="White"/>
                <NavigationViewItem 
                     Icon="Globe"       
                     Content="Query Info1" 
                     Tag="QueryCompany" 
                     Background="DarkBlue"  Foreground="White"/>
                <NavigationViewItem 
                     Icon="PostUpdate"  
                     Content="Query Info2"      
                     Tag="QueryJob"     
                     Background="DarkBlue"  
                     Foreground="White"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
        </NavigationView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The only way I know to do this is just to throw away the nav control and return just use buttons on a grid...  Or maybe define a template that turns off the highlighting for selected... Anyways, I was trying to stick with the Nav Control just to be standard and to gain the automatically resizing feature...

Answer (score 0):

Set SelectedIndex to null from SelectionChanged Event to cause the Navigation Tab to untoggled and act like a button. Prior to 1803, the SelectedIndex property was readonly from SelectionChanged Event and required setting using Dispatcher.

```
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                      Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                     () => {
                          NavView.SelectedItem = null;
                          NavView.Header = "myHeader;
                });
```

However, in 1803, this trick nolonger works, eventhough the SelectedItem property is nolonger readonly from SelectionChanged Event.  Using Dispatcher in 1803 to set SelectionIndex to null causes an infinite recursive loop.